# Name of this Vine

Tags: vines

I was passing by a school and i saw this vine and i like the shape of leaves of this vine so took a cutting from it, does anyone know the name of this

I plant the cutting of it in mixture of peat moss + perlite and watered it

[image]

Comment: Please, could you add whereabouts in the world you found it? Also, a description of the parent plant would help.

Comment: I live in Saudi Arabia. dont know any thing about it so just like pothos i planted its cuttings in potting soil. So far the leaves are green  Some are closed but still soft and green and stem is also soft. Will check for new roots after one month.